# how to enter text into uitextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have implemented the delegates for `UITextField` and also method for these text field. Below are the methods:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}



- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)aTextField
{

    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

My problem is that when I want to enter text into `UITextField` its delegate does not allow me to enter the text into textfields. Kindly tell me how i can enter the data into textfields

Answer (score 2):

Remove the textFieldDidBeginEditing code.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

tells the app that the keyboard is no longer required for the text field.

So you are saying...

When I start editing the text field, hide the keyboard and stop editing the text field.

You also need to add...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i have linked the textfields with the delegate . i remove the this method still is it not working i am not able to enter text into textfield

Comment: Have you implemented the <UITextFieldDelegate> protocol in the ViewController that you are setting as the delegate?

Comment: yes i implement this protocol

Comment: You need to implement - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField also see edit.

Comment: Any chance of getting an accept for this if it solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you tap on the textField this `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate method will work first.

You are dismissing the keyboard in that delegate method like: `[textField resignFirstResponder];` remove that line. Everything will be fine.

Comment: i have remove that line problem is still there i am not able to enter text in textfields

Comment: @adnan Is the keyboard is coming ? if not add `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` in the beginediting.